using IMPORTXML to import dynamic table
When I'm trying to load data from https://2e.aonprd.com/Backgrounds.aspx, the table doesn't seem to initially load, resulting in what seems to be an empty data set.
Is there a way to use importxml to load the entire data set?
Formula:
=IMPORTXML("https://2e.aonprd.com/Backgrounds.aspx","//*[contains(@id,results)]/div[2]/div/table")

Shows:


Following this. It seems that Google sheets cannot accomplish what you want. You might want to consider using different tools

Fetching dynamic site using Google Sheets
Following discussions like this and related Stackoverflow posts like this Google Sheets seems to be lacking the capability of fetching sites that uses dynamic data. Also, the site that you are trying to access may also be implementing ways to avoid web scrapers from accessing their data. I tried scraping it using Apps Script but it gave almost the same data as you are getting (seen from the screenshot you provided).
Output Using Apps Script

You can check this SO post for possible ways to scrape a dynamic website like the one you are trying to.
References:
Unable to Get Website Data using =importxml
ImportHTML table but values are missing
How to scrape dynamic content from a website?
